# logstash parsing lines that only contains value & fetch several items from it

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I've log input lines.
I want my filer to filter only lines that have the "Add" word within it
(this word can be at anywhere at line)
and extract some values from line

to get something like: (at json format)

```
Action: Add, val1: 12, val2: 15
Action: Add, val1: 11, val2: 12
```

from those lines input

```
ifoeife, Add, val1:12, val2:15
eife, frfr, 90088, Add, val1:11, val2:12
eife, val1:11, val2:12
```

[val1, val2, action are indexes]

Comment: I understand it is a regex that match the line but I don't understand how to produce from it the new format

Answer (score 0):

Well. You can use Grok filter. It is possible to create some kind of complicated pattern or just use Regular expressions as described here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_regular_expressions

Regexp for your line would be something like
`[a-zA-Z0-9,]*?(Add|SomeOtherPossibleAction), (val1:\d+), (val2:\d+)`